# Call PrimeFaces from the Google Chrome developer console

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

First a bit of background, I have access to a site where when I click on one day of the week (is something like a calendar on screen for the month) where every day from Mon to Fri have a number of appointments.

The website timeouts after like 12 min of inactivity. So I implemented a small js script that I run from the console to call one of the primefaces functions, like this:

```
PrimeFaces.ab({s:"forRemApp:Month",p:"forRegApp:Month",u:"forRegApp:schedule"})
```

Now, I don't want to stay in the site all day waiting for appointments, I want to refresh the screen and let me know if there are appointments in any days (that is already done). But from there I have to do that manually

That works, and what this does is refresh the scren, and when the new appointments are available, the code let me know playing a sound, so I can click (will load a new screen for that day in that calendar), click on the time available on that day and click to make an appointment, etc.

Everything is good so far, the issue is I'm very curious about this and want to go beyond that, my javascript is very basic but I know that the website used jquery (I saw something referring to a jsf file, jquery and sizzlejs)

I know the backend is in java, I have set a breakpoint in the dev console and when I click it (a day with appointments) always call a function that is in the following file (with all the DOM information in it about who I clicked passed as a parameter)

This is the code that gets called when I click:

```
https://pastebin.com/UWVTC9CD
```

specifically the function

```
if (!(cc = ce.handle)) {
            cc = ce.handle = function(cl) {
                return typeof bI !== aC && (!cl || bI.event.triggered 
!== cl.type) ? bI.event.dispatch.apply(cc.elem, arguments) : undefined
}
;
cc.elem = b8
}
```

and it unfolds from there, calling several functions, checking the object that was clicked, etc and finally loading the screen (which belongs to the calendar) for selecting the time available for that day.

I want to automate that call to a single function call from the developer console, by passing the parameter (object I suppose) that will be the day I chose to click but I will not click,

My code simple calls

```
PrimeFaces.ab({s:"forRegApp:Month",p:"forRegApp:Month",u:"forRegApp:schedule"})
```

every few seconds and scan that DOM for searching the available appointments (a number) and plays a sound to let me know.

Any advise on how to call that from the javascript console so I can go to the next screen automatically and select the appointment right away?

Comment: when you say "calendar" do you mean the PrimeFaces Schedule component like this one here:  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml .  If so I think it should be possible I might be able to help you figure out how to "click" on a day.

Comment: Is very similar, but not the looks, the internals are really similar, seems to me that in my case they are using a different skin or it is just a slighly older version, in the one you sent me I see the same 'fc-day ui-widget-content' and similars in the source code, and also this one have the same buttons for Month, Day, Week. Any idea? I mean I put a breakpoint for 'click' and whenever I click on it I got the same file (the pastebin url I put in the post), but I don't see any clue how to get to the next screen by calling a function or something, the next screen have appointments to select

Comment: One detail is that in my case I click on "Day" I get a screen that is exactly (not in colors but in structure) to the one on the demo you sent, with hours for that day to select from. What I want to achieve is check appointments, when they are available the DOM scan will tell me, and this is my issue I need to know how to compose a call to emulate that function when one clicks by calling the 'right' function in there to go to the next screen when the hours are (that screen is very similar when you click on "Day" in your demo).

Comment: See my answer below. It should get you a lot further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think I have a solution for you to help you.

1.Navigate to this URL: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml

2.Open the Chrome JavaScript Console.

3.Type the following and press ENTER to advance to the next day:

```
PrimeFaces.widgets.myschedule.jqc.fullCalendar('next');
```

4.Type the following and press ENTER to enter the "day" display I think you want:

```
PrimeFaces.widgets.myschedule.jqc.fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
```

That should navigate you to the view you want.  Now to figure out on your page what the name of the widget is you can just type "PrimeFaces.widgets." and let Chrome give you a list of widgets.  It may be some trial an error for you to figure out which widget is the schedule it may be named something like "jidt687" or something uniquely obscure.

PrimeFaces Schedule is based on FullCalendar.js so if you want to see any other calls you can make the docs are here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-navigation

That will show you can do "today", "next", "previous", "previousYear" etc. etc.

Comment: First of all, you are very amazing, thanks for sharing your knowledge with me. 
Very much appreciated. I have some questions.
Facing the full calendar for the month (now there are no appointments, but I'm testing)
If I call:
    PrimeFaces.widgets.myschedule.jqc.fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
It will go to the day schedule but will Not make an http request.

Comment: then I tried to call
    PrimeFaces.widgets.myschedule.jqc.fullCalendar('next');
Here I didn't see an http request either, both from the Network log in the dev console 
and from tcpdump(1), none. 
But, if I click manually on Day in the top (loading the Day screen) then the following call to:
    PrimeFaces.widgets.myschedule.jqc.fullCalendar('next');
Works!. That make the http request as expected. And (correct me if I'm wrong that will
trigger the loading of Data from the website with the appointments when they are ready.

Comment: Now, my question is, how can I fix this? I don't mind to click on the 'Day' button and then
put the script but if I can do it automatic that will be very amazing.

Another question: How can I (remember, my javascript is very basic) know if the call to "next"
is successfull or not? from the return value? I'm asking because this site gets
so congested that when making appointments the POST method fails a LOT, I saw
that in my last appointment and they fail 20 o 22 tries.

Comment: My other question: In that grid, panel (for the day), etc they have the time of that day
when they make the appointments available as links (i.e: 9:00am - 3 appointments available)
or something like that, when one click on the link you get a popup window and then
you put a captcha for confirming the appointment, how can I get the 'list' of
appointments from that day? If possible, how can I even get further by detecting an
available appointment and launching the popup window (emulating the click on it)
for putting the captcha?

Again, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I would have to keep messing around with it to see, I just wanted to give you the tools for how the PrimeFaces Widgets worked and how you can manipulate them!

Comment: You are correct, that is very fair, I want to take this moment  to again thank you for your help, it was very important. have an excellent day.